# Python Requests HTTP Response 406

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, request

I have my own domain where an json file is stored (`http://example.com/file.json)`. When accesing the file in browser using the direct link, the json is returned just fine. But when using the same approach in my python code below, the http response is **406**. Any ideas why?

```
import requests
url = 'http://example.com/file.json'
r = requests.get(url, headers={"Accept":"text/html"})
print(r.status_code)
print(r.headers)
```

Prints:

```
406
{'Server': 'nginx/1.14.1', 'Date': 'Sun, 12 May 2019 16:53:25 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=iso-8859-1', 'Content-Length': '226', 'Connection': 'k
eep-alive'}
```

Comment: Sounds like you might need to add an `accept` header to the  request.

Comment: @MarkMeyer do you have any example, please? I don't see anything like that in the doc. https://2.python-requests.org//en/latest/api/

Comment: @Mark: The Requests module includes "accept */*" by default.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Solved by using a different User-Agent. The default Python User-Agent `'python-requests/2.21.0'` was being probably blocked by the hosting company.

```
r = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": "XY"})
```

Some of the possible agents: [List of User Agent strings](https://deviceatlas.com/blog/list-of-user-agent-strings)

Comment: also, if you'd just like to use the UA sent out by your browser, you can get it here: https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent

Answer (score -1):

Your own accepted answer is most likely incorrect. This error means the value of `Accept` header does not match `Content-Type` of the response. If you'd send `Accept: */*` , it would work (at least the `406` would not be returned).

Comment: I agree, this makes more sense... but I just encountered this same problem, and checked, and "Accept: */*" was included (by default) in the request header. Further, changing the User-Agent as suggested worked. Weird that my (big player) web-host bans Python Requests by default.

Comment: While that's the _classic_ 406 behavior you'd expect, it turns out some hosts block requests made with the default User-Agent while returning a 406, as @DNac pointed out. See this other question for another example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57417799/i-call-api-from-python-i-get-the-response-406-not-acceptable