# How to extract all pages URL from a website using python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want a list of all pages URL from a website. Following code does not return anything:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

base_url = 'http://www.techadvisorblog.com'
response = requests.get(base_url + '/a')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

urls = []

for tr in soup.select('tbody tr'):
    urls.append(base_url + tr.td.a['href'])
```

Comment: Can you indicate part of the desired output? And why are you concatenating '/a' onto the end which re-directs to `https://techadvisorblog.com/about-us/`

Answer (score 0):

The response from the backend is 406.
You can overcome that by specifying the user agent.

```
>>> response = requests.get(base_url + '/a', headers={"User-Agent": "XY"})
```

[Python Requests HTTP Response 406](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56101612/python-requests-http-response-406)

You can get the urls

```
>>> for link in soup.find_all('a'):
...     print(link.get('href'))
...
#content
https://techadvisorblog.com/
https://techadvisorblog.com
https://techadvisorblog.com/contact-us/
https://techadvisorblog.com/about-us/
https://techadvisorblog.com/disclaimer/
https://techadvisorblog.com/privacy-policy/
None
https://techadvisorblog.com/
https://techadvisorblog.com
https://techadvisorblog.com/contact-us/
https://techadvisorblog.com/about-us/
https://techadvisorblog.com/disclaimer/
https://techadvisorblog.com/privacy-policy/
None
https://techadvisorblog.com/
https://www.instagram.com/techadvisorblog
//www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=https://techadvisorblog.com/about-us/
https://techadvisorblog.com/contact-us/
https://techadvisorblog.com/
https://techadvisorblog.com/what-is-world-wide-web-www/
https://techadvisorblog.com/best-free-password-manager-for-windows-10/
https://techadvisorblog.com/solved-failed-to-start-emulator-the-emulator-was-not-properly-closed/
https://techadvisorblog.com/is-telegram-safe/
https://techadvisorblog.com/will-technology-ever-rule-the-world/
https://techadvisorblog.com/category/android/
https://techadvisorblog.com/category/knowledge/basic-computer/
https://techadvisorblog.com/category/games/
https://techadvisorblog.com/category/knowledge/
https://techadvisorblog.com/category/security/
http://Techadvisorblog.com/
http://Techadvisorblog.com
None
None
None
None
None
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are concatenating \a on the end of url as this re-directs to the about-us page. Also, I see no table/tr/td tags to work with on base url or about-us. Instead, if you meant to cycle through the two pages (or more) that are the pagination for the base url you can do this by testing for the presence of the `rel` attribute with value `next`. And yes, you need a valid User-Agent header.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36',
}

page = 1
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers = headers
    while True:
        r = s.get(f'https://techadvisorblog.com/page/{page}/')
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        print(soup.select_one('title').text)
        if soup.select_one('[rel=next]') is None:
            break
        page+=1
```