# Getting "406 Not Acceptable" when trying to scrape web using Python

Tags: python, python-requests

I am new to Python and web scraping. I am trying to scrape articles from a website but getting "406 Not Acceptable" when I run this code. Please help.

```
from requests import get
source_site_home_page = "https://www.readlightnovel.org/"
r = get(source_site_home_page)
print(r.text)
```

Comment: You are maybe sending too many requests too quickly. Does happen for the first request you make?

Comment: Does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56101612/python-requests-http-response-406

Comment: When I ran your code I'm getting output

Comment: @HenryLeBerre I got the same error when I sent a request for the first time.

Comment: @HenryLeBerre I have tried by adding user agent and it's throwing response code 200. No output. I am sorry if this is a dumb question/explanation. I have just watched a video on python scraping and started coding.

Comment: @VishalUpadhyay What could be the reason? Why I'm not getting the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the user agent flags like in this thread :
[Python Requests HTTP Response 406](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56101612/python-requests-http-response-406)

`r.status_code`gives you code 200 because the request was successful!

The contents of the page should be in `r.text`