# scraping with request with bs4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am try to scrape this page  getting a 406 error. what am i doing wrong please?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url="http://chucknorrisfacts.net/facts"

response = request.get(url)
print(response)
```

Comment: this is not [ask] a question, but see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56101612/python-requests-http-response-406, you probably need a user agent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the headers parameter:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url="http://chucknorrisfacts.net/facts"
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.66 Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
print(response)
```